# What is the difference between using ipfw and hosts.deny in terms of security?

Tags: security, mac-osx-server, ipfw, denyhosts

I'm in the middle of securing an OSX server that is the target of hundreds of automated requests per second from Chinese, Russian and US servers (see: [Recovering a server from being an open relay](https://serverfault.com/questions/303647/recovering-a-server-from-being-an-open-relay)).

I've used `ipfw` to set up rules that exclude all but local IP requests (i.e. 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16).

What is the difference between setting up `ipfw` rules, and implementing similar rules in `hosts.allow`/`hosts.deny`?

As I understand it, the `hosts` files affect tcp-wrapped services (so may not be as holistic as `ipfw`). Would that also mean that they come *after* the firewall (so no point in using both)?

Comment: From security standpoint there IS a point in using both ipfw and tcp-wrappers because multi-layered defence is more reliable. In practice it sometimes happens that firewall get temporarily disabled for some purpose and not re-enabled for days and weeks by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` are, so to say, deprecated. They are mainly used for tcp-wrapper and maybe used by other services or applications. But *if* they are used depends on the implementation of the program.

Using a firewall is the preferred method because their rules are based on IPs, ports and other criteria. The firewall is independent of the application listening on the IP/port and therefore always catches the traffic.

And yes the `hosts.*` files are effective *after* the firewall. That said, you do not need them.

Comment: deprecated? Says who? TCP wrappers (which is the only system using hosts.accept/deny - not mostly, and is not itself a service / application) provides functionality not available in ipfw (and vice versa).

Comment: @symcbean Interesting, can you expand on that gap in functionality?

Comment: TCP wrappers can call userspace code (see twist, spawn) and link ident lookups (by default ident security is non-existent - but there are extensions). OTOH stuff like rate limiting, masquerading, port redirection are much simpler using the firewall.

Comment: You can also allow by DNS entries with hosts.allow, ie `sshd: .domain.com EXCEPT PARANOID` to only allow hosts from *.domain.com with valid forward and reverse DNS entries.